# Completely remove all duplicate words in list

Tags: python, list, set

I'm receiving data from user and adding list. How can i delete all duplicate from list.

For example user Input are: California, Orange, New York, Orange

I want delete completely duplicate items(orange) and just want show as output : California, New York

```
list = []
n = int(input("How many word : "))

for i in range(0,n):
    word = str(input()) 
    list.append(word)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use some mapping data structure to count your items and then filter for those whose count is `1`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
n = int(input("How many word : "))

for i in range(0,n):
    word = str(input()) 
    d[word] += 1

lst = [k for k in d if d[k] == 1]
```